# Wrong permission when accessing ZFS snapshot over NFS (Solaris server, Ubuntu client)

Tags: nfs, zfs, file-permissions, solaris-10

TL;DR: I don't understand why I can access one file but not an other (in the same directory), although they appear to have identical permissions.

---

I have an NFS server running Solaris 10 10/08 and a client on Ubuntu 12.04. I mount a ZFS snapshot like this:

```
# mount | grep homes
server:/homes/.zfs/snapshot on /u/homes type nfs (ro,noatime,vers=3,intr,sloppy,addr=1.2.3.4)
```

Then I look at these two files in `/u/homes`:

```
# ls -l 1.txt 2.txt 
-rw-r--r--+ 1 usr grp 2.2K Oct 12 13:42 1.txt
-rw-r--r--+ 1 usr grp 2.1K May 31  2013 2.txt


# stat 1.txt
  File: `1.txt'
  Size: 2170        Blocks: 4          IO Block: 1048576 regular file
Device: 43h/67d Inode: 1621536     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 2428/   usr)   Gid: ( 2000/    grp)
 Birth: -

# stat 2.txt
  File: `2.txt'
  Size: 2146        Blocks: 3          IO Block: 1048576 regular file
Device: 43h/67d Inode: 7975730     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 2428/   usr)   Gid: ( 2000/    grp)
 Birth: -
```

Same files when viewed on the server:

```
  File: `1.txt'
  Size: 2170            Blocks: 4          IO Block: 2560   regular file
Device: 2d50005h/47513605d      Inode: 1621536     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 2428/ UNKNOWN)   Gid: ( 2000/ UNKNOWN)

  File: `2.txt'
  Size: 2146            Blocks: 3          IO Block: 2560   regular file
Device: 2d50005h/47513605d      Inode: 7975730     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 2428/ UNKNOWN)   Gid: ( 2000/ UNKNOWN)
```

They look very similar to me. Now when I try to access them from the client, I get

```
# cat 2.txt >/dev/null; echo $?
0
# cat 1.txt >/dev/null; echo $?
cat: 1.txt: Permission denied
1
```

How's that? They have identical permissions! I also `snoop`-ed the NFS packets on the server side and there was no difference in communication (other than packet lengths, checksums, timestamps etc.), but one file returns

```
NFS:  Access = read
```

and the other

```
NFS:  Access =
```

How can this be and what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT1**

```
# zfs get all homes | sort
NAME   PROPERTY              VALUE                       SOURCE
homes  aclinherit            restricted                  default
homes  aclmode               groupmask                   default
homes  atime                 on                          default
homes  available             1.36T                       -
homes  canmount              on                          default
homes  casesensitivity       sensitive                   -
homes  checksum              on                          default
homes  compression           on                          inherited from homes
homes  compressratio         1.57x                       -
homes  copies                1                           default
homes  creation              Mon Aug 17 18:53 2015       -
homes  devices               on                          default
homes  exec                  on                          default
homes  logbias               latency                     default
homes  mounted               yes                         -
homes  mountpoint            /homes                      local
homes  nbmand                off                         default
homes  normalization         none                        -
homes  primarycache          all                         default
homes  quota                 none                        default
homes  readonly              off                         inherited from homes
homes  recordsize            128K                        default
homes  referenced            800G                        -
homes  refquota              none                        default
homes  refreservation        none                        default
homes  reservation           none                        default
homes  secondarycache        all                         default
homes  setuid                on                          default
homes  shareiscsi            off                         default
homes  sharenfs              on                          inherited from homes
homes  sharesmb              off                         default
homes  snapdir               hidden                      default
homes  type                  filesystem                  -
homes  used                  1.31T                       -
homes  usedbychildren        0                           -
homes  usedbydataset         800G                        -
homes  usedbyrefreservation  0                           -
homes  usedbysnapshots       544G                        -
homes  utf8only              off                         -
homes  version               4                           -
homes  vscan                 off                         default
homes  xattr                 on                          default
homes  zoned                 off                         default


# zfs get all homes@backup_2016-01-21 | sort
NAME                      PROPERTY              VALUE                  SOURCE
homes@backup_2016-01-21  casesensitivity       sensitive              -
homes@backup_2016-01-21  compressratio         1.53x                  -
homes@backup_2016-01-21  creation              Thu Jan 21  0:00 2016  -
homes@backup_2016-01-21  defer_destroy         off                    -
homes@backup_2016-01-21  devices               on                     default
homes@backup_2016-01-21  exec                  on                     default
homes@backup_2016-01-21  nbmand                off                    default
homes@backup_2016-01-21  normalization         none                   -
homes@backup_2016-01-21  primarycache          all                    default
homes@backup_2016-01-21  referenced            800G                   -
homes@backup_2016-01-21  secondarycache        all                    default
homes@backup_2016-01-21  setuid                on                     default
homes@backup_2016-01-21  shareiscsi            off                    default
homes@backup_2016-01-21  type                  snapshot               -
homes@backup_2016-01-21  used                  0                      -
homes@backup_2016-01-21  userrefs              0                      -
homes@backup_2016-01-21  utf8only              off                    -
homes@backup_2016-01-21  version               4                      -
homes@backup_2016-01-21  xattr                 on                     default
```

**EDIT2**

```
# share
-               /homes   rw   ""
```

Comment: Can you post the output of "zfs get all /homes/.zfs/snapshot" and "share" ?

Comment: yeah, see edit .

Comment: and the command "share" ;)

Comment: sorry, missed that, here it comes

Comment: Are there any ACLs on the files?  What's the output from `ls -v 1.txt 2.txt` run on the Solaris server?  What `stat` command are you using?  It's likely non-native and isn't aware of ZFS ACLs.

Comment: Ah, a very good point! While 2.txt reruns a list of various ACL properties, 1.txt (the one that causes troubles) doesn't list any ACLs!

Comment: Andrew, if you submit your reply as an answer (basically a hint to check for ACLs using `ls -v`), I will accept it as the correct answer.